# custom payment gateway change name

Tags: magento-1.9, module, payment-methods

Does any body knows how to change the Payment information name of Custom Payment Module.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

Check for **system > configuration > sale tab > Payment Methods** and change **Title** of you desired payment method.

**Second**

go to **app/code/local or community/Spacename/Modulename/etc/config.xml**

and search for following **xml nodes**  and change **Title** their

```
   <default>
    <payment>     
        <title>here</title>
    </payment>
  </default>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know in which file you need to change the name, you can use Magento template path hints here :  **system> configuration > Advanced > Developer** .

than switch to **current store under Current configuration scope**

than **enable template path hints** under **Debug**, than under Shipping method you can see from which file the label "**cardpayment**
" is coming from....

Also in some modules, they mentioned that Name under **System > Configuration > Payment methods > Title**....